# Using weak Veracrypt password safe?

Tags: encryption, passwords, attacks, veracrypt, key

Is it safe to create a Veracrypt partition (on a USB) such that

- it takes up the whole device (ie. not a "file", but using the USB as the storage container)
- it contains only a standard volume (no hidden volume)
- it uses a weak password (eg. `123456`)
- it is quick formatted (ie. not overwritten with garbage)
- no one obtains the volume header during this time (while the weak password is in use)

I then easily mount and dismount the Veracrypt container adding files. After I am done (eg. after a few days or a week), I change the volume password (eg. from `123456` to `Zdbze5CVPFTPUrPbxzM4GG3N8sTnAktRRcFyYftkdWsUg`).

I am concerned that by initially using a weak password then changing it to a sufficiently strong password, the security is reduced.

In particular, if an attacker tries to recover the volume header (of the weak password) from the start and end of the partition, they can use either the complex password (`Zdbze5CVPFTPUrPbxzM4GG3N8sTnAktRRcFyYftkdWsUg`) or the weak password (`123456`) to unlock the Veracrypt container.

Comment: Closely related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18479/how-does-truecrypt-change-password-without-the-need-for-a-complete-re-encryption This is for truecrypt but it's the same algorithm (or better) for vera, afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the master key is encrypted (wrapped) using the password. If this wrapped key is *overwritten* by the same key wrapped with the secure password (using password based encryption, as Veracrypt uses) then the result should be secure.

The problem with flash based storage is that it may not actually overwrite the password but write it to another page (because of wear leveling). Direct access to the flash may then be used to retrieve the old wrapped password, and a brute force attack could then be used to retrieve the master key. This will not be easy to do, but it isn't impossible.

More information [in this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18483/1172).

Comment: Then what if I do not initially do a quick format, but a full format? (so that all bits on the device appear to be random such that it is not plausible to try all subset as the volume header)? (since volume header may be stored anywhere due to wear-levelling)

Comment: A full format is never a good idea on a flash device. If you have an SSD then you can probably perform a SATA *secure erase* instead (there is an identical function on NVMe SSD's, I think). But as you only change the passwords *after* putting the data on the SSD it won't matter much. Note that flash devices commonly have spare pages of flash for the wear leveling, the full format may therefore *not destroy all data*! Actually, same for HDD's, as damaged sectors may be replaced by spare ones internally. And secure erase is *way faster* even on HDD's than a full format.

Comment: The chances that the data is moved to another sector because of damage is *way* lower on HDD's. And I presume that Veracrypt will try and write the data at the same location (it's kind of hinted that way, but I didn't perform a code review). So don't do this on a HDD with many SMART errors (but you'd toss that HDD in the bin anyway, *right*?)

Comment: Note that many cheap USB sticks won't do too much wear leveling, but unfortunately you'll never know what they do, so...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the old header is properly rewritten, it is safe. But especially on a USB flash device (also SSDs), this assumption is likely not true because of wear-leveling. So I would recommend strongly against this.