# Securely changing Veracrypt password

Tags: encryption, passwords, attacks, veracrypt, key

**How can I change a Veracrypt (master) password efficiently and securely?**

Based on the answers [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/184587/), it is not safe to use `system --> change password` due to various reasons.

I cannot simply image the device to my hard drive as it does not use FDE (I am in the process of moving towards full encryption); doing so would allow attackers to get the master key that is encrypted with a weak password from the hard drive (rather than from the device that will use a complex password).

The best solution I have come up with so far is to:

- create a Veracrypt container on the hard drive using a strong one-time password (that is used to temporarily store the image of the device)
- image the device and store in temporary Veracrypt container
- delete old Veracrypt partition (with a weak password)
- create a new Veracrypt partition on top (with a complex password)
- move files from image to new Veracrypt partition

Comment: Is it right to guess the major risk you want to fight are the blocks stored unencrypted outside of your weak Veracrypt container because of the normal behaviour of your operating system? If my guess is right, please clarify your purpose in your original question.

Comment: Your disk is full of leaks "unencrypted"? Depending on your disk driver, and your disk firmware, some of them aren't reachable now.

Comment: @danielAzuelos No, your guess is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work well enough and I believe it is the best one possible currently without destroying the USB flash drive. The problem is that the old container may leave remnants for the same reasons, why it is insecure to change the password. Namely wear-leveling.

If these remnants include the header, the attacker may be able to retrieve some files, that were not overwritten. If you are really really serious about having the data 100% secure, you should put the new container on a new flash-stick and properly destroy the old one with the container with weak password.

Alternatively, as ThoriumBR mentioned, you may decrease the chance of the remnants surviving by writing random data to the flash drive (for example making largest possible empty VeraCrypt volume and also choosing the secure deletition). This does not guarantee the data will be destroyed properly, but it increases the chance somewhat. Repeated writing to the flash memory will however lower its life-expectancy, so the flash drive will be more likely to fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "should mostly work"?

Comment: @jvkbzowtb Well, I described the caveat. The header of the old container may survive as well as parts of the old container. If the header survives, it should be possible for the attacker to decrypt the surviving parts of the old container and obtain the data on them.

Answer (score 0):

Security is not reduced if you change the weak password with a strong password compared to using a strong password in the first place.

Both weak and strong passwords unlock your volume/container key which is then used for volume/container access.

The key has the same strength. The fact that you use a strong password to access it is fine and unrelated to the previously weak password.

Comment: If the medium does wear leveling, this is untrue.

Comment: Why ? The data itself is encrypted using the key anyway.

Comment: Because the master key is encrypted with the weak key, and if you change the password on a system with wear leveling, it won't overwrite the weakly encrypted master key.

Comment: True, but it's highly unlikely that you find that weakly encrypted key just from wear-leveling junk.The key is just some random data with no specific tag to be identified with.

Comment: It'd actually be really easy to find it. If you know it's at least _somewhere_, you can iteratively attempt all address ranges of the correct size and you'll find it pretty soon. Even if you hid a 32 byte random password on a terabyte of random data, you could still find that 32 bytes and use them in short order.

Comment: There is no easy way to know where that value starts and where it ends.

Comment: So? The number of combinations is small enough that you can brute force it.

Comment: In theory, let's say we have 512GB SSD. Trying all 32-byte on it can take 8.*0^18 -2 tries (16M*512G if my math was right, which is < 90 days with good Tfop class video card). But this assumes a lot: that fake-bad blocks have been marked or that nothing did overwrite the free space (this one should be obvious for anyone), which is the easiest way to clean an SSD of data. So in practice, it won't work unless fake bad blocks that are still readable exist and by coincidence they contain the wanted string. Flat chance. We can test this relatively easy in practice. P.S. Author mentioned HDD - NoWL.

Comment: @Overmind Not sure where your math is coming from, I'd figure you'd be trying every possible consecutive 32 bytes, which is 512*10^9 - 31. In reality I expect it would be much less, since the key(s) are stored in a specific location, you'd only have to check one part of each block.

Comment: Wear leveling is a bugaboo of little reality. None of the standard forensic labs are capable of doing anything with it. A specialty lab capable of doing *Chip-Off* work to bypass the wear leveling controllers to get to the swapped memory would be very very expensive. Even then, trying to correlate the dissociated tiny memory fragments with useful content is yet another Herculean undertaking. **Wear leveling is simply not a realistic threat.**

Comment: @user10216038 "Realistic" depends on threat model. It also depends on how large the encrypted key is and how many sectors it spans. It _certainly_ fits within a single flash page.

Answer (score -2):

You can just create another container with a strong password, copy all files from the weak encrypted container to the new, and secure-delete the older one.

If your disk is a SSD, secure delete will not work because of wear leveling. In this case, you could create a very large file full of zeroes to fill up the disk, delete it, fill up again. Every time you do that, you decrease the chance of recovering the original headers (and decrease the lifespan of your device).

Comment: There is no way to actually ensure the proper deletion of flash memory, please don't promote approaches, that mask the problem without solving it.

Comment: Note that I said _decrease the chance_. I never said it will ensure deletion. I know the only way to ensure deletion is physical destruction, but that is really needed in very, very few cases.

Comment: Even so, not everyone here will go and search for one exact word used. Critical things like these need to be emphasized.

Comment: @PeterHarmann Are we not trusting the SECURE ERASE ATA function?

Comment: @Adonalsium no we **are not!** And it is not even applicable for USBs. Read here: https://skrilnetz.net/the-truth-about-how-to-securely-erase-a-solid-state-drive-ssd/

Comment: I see the point that we can't know that the manufacturer implemented SECURE ERASE properly. I dislike that article because it implies that a quick erase is an insecure erase.

Comment: Creating a large file full of zeros and deleting it will **not** wipe an SSD, due to overprovisioning.

Comment: @forest : fully agreed. This method **cannot fully wipe** any kind of persistent storage: USB key, SSD, rotationnal disk. Mind the driver, the cache, and the reallocation algorithm.